# How to plot a dataframe column of lists as horizontal lines

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have a Dataframe with the column `'all_maxs'` that could have a list of different values.

```py
          c            all_maxs
38  50804.6           [50883.3]
39  50743.9           [50883.3]
40  50649.9           [50883.3]
41  50508.3           [50883.3]
42  50577.6           [50883.3]
43  50703.0           [50883.3]
44  50793.7           [50883.3]
45  50647.8  [50883.3, 50813.1]
46  50732.8  [50883.3, 50813.1]
47  50673.2  [50883.3, 50813.1]

df.plot(y='c')
```

### Current Result

[image]

I need to plot column `'c'`, and the values of column `'all_maxs'` that should be horizontal lines.

### Expected Result

[image: expected result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Verify the `'all_maxs'` values are `list` type.
2. Extract values from the lists and plot them as horizontal lines.

   - `df = df.dropna()` if there are any `NaN`

### Imports and DataFrame

- Convert the `'all_maxs'` column type from `str` to `list` if needed, using [`ast.liter_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

```py
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval

data =\
{38: {'all_maxs': '[50883.3]', 'c': 50804.6},
 39: {'all_maxs': '[50883.3]', 'c': 50743.9},
 40: {'all_maxs': '[50883.3]', 'c': 50649.9},
 41: {'all_maxs': '[50883.3]', 'c': 50508.3},
 42: {'all_maxs': '[50883.3]', 'c': 50577.6},
 43: {'all_maxs': '[50883.3]', 'c': 50703.0},
 44: {'all_maxs': '[50883.3]', 'c': 50793.7},
 45: {'all_maxs': '[50883.3, 50813.1]', 'c': 50647.8},
 46: {'all_maxs': '[50883.3, 50813.1]', 'c': 50732.8},
 47: {'all_maxs': '[50883.3, 50813.1]', 'c': 50673.2}}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')

# reorder the columns to match the OP
df = df[['c', 'all_maxs']]

# print a value from all_maxs to see the type
>>> print(type(df.loc[38, 'all_maxs']))
str

# currently the all_max values are strings, which must be converted to list type
df.all_maxs = df.all_maxs.apply(literal_eval)

# print a value from all_maxs to see the type
>>> print(type(df.loc[38, 'all_maxs']))
list
```

### Plot

- Plot the dataframe directly with [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

  - `xticks=df.index` will make an xtick for every value in the index, but if there are many values crowding the x-axis, remove this parameter.
- Use [`matplotlib.pyplot.hlines`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hlines.html), which will accept a list of values, to plot the unique values from `'all_max'` as horizontal lines.

  - Use [`pandas.DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) to remove all the values from lists, and then drop duplicates with [`.drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)
  - `y=` will be the remaining values in the `'all_maxs'` column
  - `xmin=` will be the remaining index values
  - `xmax=` will be the max value in the index plotted from `df`

```py
ax = df.plot(y='c', legend=False, figsize=(8, 5), xticks=df.index)

# extract all the values from all_maxs, drop the duplicates
all_maxs = df.all_maxs.explode().drop_duplicates().to_frame()

# add the horizontal lines
ax.hlines(y=all_maxs.all_maxs, xmin=all_maxs.index, xmax=df.index.max(), color='k')
```

[image]

Comment: The code is perfect. What I tried to do to reach the same result was much slower. I'm sorry for my bad question. Next time I will follow your corrections. Thank you

Comment: @Gabriele it wasn’t a bad question, it just didn’t have all the necessary information or code expected of a SO question. Dealing with lists in a data frame and plotting them is actually an interesting question. I’m glad this works for you.